# Drive needs to be formatted in Windows 7

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

After an improper shutdown, my Windows 7 stopped booting and instead displayed "The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible. Error code: 0xc000000e" When I plug the drive in as an external on a working computer, I get the message that the drive needs to be formatted. If I go into disk management, it lists that partition type as RAW.

However, when I use disk tools such as TestDisk 6.14, I am able to list and copy files. Also, the partition type is recognized as NTFS. This leads me to believe that there must be a way to fix this so that Windows can recognize it just like TestDisk does.

I also ran chkdsk /r on the drive and got the message "Unable to read the Usn Journal $J data stream".

Any ideas, anyone? FYI this is an SSD drive.

Comment: Please head back to Server Fault, register your account, then use the same login here to associate your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to [recover the partition table](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#Partition_table_recovery)? Quoting the TestDisk wiki:

> It's now possible to write the new partition structure.
>
> Note: The extended partition is automatically set. TestDisk recognizes this
> using the different partition structure.
>
> [image]
> If all partitions are listed and only in this case, confirm at Write
> with Enter, y and OK.
>
> Now, the partitions are registered in the partition table.

**Update:** If you open the disk with [gparted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) or some [similar tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PartitionMagic), do you see the partitions as *unformatted*, or do you see the entire disk as *unpartitioned space*?

My guess is that you somehow lost the partition table, but your partitions might still be intact. In that case, try to:

- make a backup of the entire disk, if possible, with a tool like `dd`
- recreate the exact same partitions as they were on the disk
- leave the partitions un-formatted, do not create a file system on any of them
- use `dd` again to write the part of the backup image that corresponds to the lost NTFS partition directly to the `/dev/sd??`
- try to mount the partition now

(Sorry, the above only applies to Linux systems, not sure how to do all that on a Windows machine.)

If the above did not work (and for that matter, if none of the things worked from the TestDisk tutorial), that probably means that the partition itself is damaged as well, in which case there's not much I can help you with, best is to try and save the files you need.

Comment: Yes I did try but it did not work.

Comment: @blizz: Before you attempt anything else with this drive, I would recommend that you use TestDisk or similar to copy your important files to another one. That way if you are forced to reformat, at least you won't lose anything of value.

Comment: Already did that, thanks. Trying to avoid formatting and reinstalling programs since i dont have product keys for everything.

Comment: Ok well thanks anyways. I tried many things but was unable to make that partition accessible from Windows. I did at least back the files up using TestDisk before formatting. I also updated the original question with the boot error so that it can be found by more people who may want to learn about TestDisk.